# Como focar um elemento

Tags: javascript, html, css, pseudo-classes

No CSS seria algo assim:

```
div {
    display: none;
}
div:active {
    display: block;
}
```

E alguma ação do usuário daria o foco a essa div pelo javascript

Sei que posso fazer adicionando e removendo uma classe/atributo porém  quero fazer sem isso

tentei, sem sucesso:

```
document.getElementByTagName('div')[0].focus();

document.activeElement = document.getElementByTagName('div')[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que você está misturando as pseudo-classes `:active` com `:focus`. A primeira ocorre quando você clica e segura o clique sobre o elemento; a segunda é quando recebe o focus — são comportamentos distintos.

Neste caso você deveria usar:

```
div:focus {
   display: block;
}
```

**Mas isso também** não funcionaria porque não é possível dar focus a um elemento oculto.

Geralmente os que podem receber focus são elementos de formulários (inputs, selects etc.); `div`s podem receber se tiverem o atributo `tabindex`, como mostra o exemplo abaixo:

```js
document.querySelector("div").focus();
```

```css
div {
   opacity: .2;
}
div:focus {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
Clique fora do texto para tirar o focus da div:
<br>
<div tabindex="1">texto</div>
```

Concluindo, seu intento não é possível de realizar, principalmente com elementos ocultos.

### Edit a pedido do autor

Como não se pode dar focus ao elemento oculto, pode colocar `opacity: 0` e `position: absolute`. Assim o elemento ficará transparente e não irá ocupar espaço no layout:

```js
document.querySelector("div").focus();
```

```css
div {
   opacity: 0;
   position: absolute;
}
div:focus {
   opacity: 1;
   position: static;
}
```

```html
Clique fora do texto para tirar o focus:
<br>
<div tabindex="1">texto</div> Texto texto
```

Comment: Então não é possível dar foco a um elemento oculto? Mesmo que seja com o `opacity: 0` em vez de `display: none`

Comment: Isso, não é possível. O opacity não faz com que o elemento seja oculto, ele continua lá, apenas não aparece porque não tem opacidade.

Comment: Com opacity é possível, porque não é oculto, como mostrei no exemplo da resposta.

Comment: Dar focus a algo que não existe na tela vai até contra o conceito da função rs... Como vou focar algo que não faz parte do layout? :)

Comment: Então até da pra fazer algo como quero... colocar o `opacity: 0; position: absolute;` no elemento sem o foco e com o foco colocar `opacity: 1; position: initial;`

Comment: coloque um exemplo na resposta pra eu aceitar